# using csharp GRPC gen imported proto file not generated

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have separated my models and service into separate files

- main.proto

```
    syntax = "proto3";
    package grpc;
    import "sub.proto";
    
    service Users {
        // SSO Adapter Profiles
      
        rpc AddUser (UserRequest) returns (UserResponse) {}
    }
```

- sub.proto

```
    syntax = "proto3";
    package grpc;
    
    
    message UserRequest {
        string FirstName = 1;
        string LastName = 2;
    }
    
    message UserResponse {
        int64  id=1;
    }
```

Using this command `protoc --proto_path=./ --csharp_out=./out/dotnet --grpc_out=./out/dotnet ./main.proto` will generate the GRPC service\client file in `.cs` but will not generate the models causing compilation error due to missing types use in the grpc APIs'.

If I move the models declaration into the `main.proto` everything works ..
Any way to keep thins separated ?

Comment: Did you try to use wild character * for multiple protofiles (./*.proto instead of ./main.proto)?

Comment: that actually helped .. I thought it would happen automatically and i wouldn't have to specify .. but indeed using wildcard worked for me..

Comment: Great. I added it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  wild character * for multiple protofiles

```
protoc --proto_path=./ --csharp_out=./out/dotnet --grpc_out=./out/dotnet ./*.proto
```

Answer (score 0):

`protoc` takes multiple proto files as an argument:

```
❯ protoc --help
Usage: protoc [OPTION] PROTO_FILES
```

You should be able to add `sub.proto` as an argument like so: `protoc --proto_path=./ --csharp_out=./out/dotnet --grpc_out=./out/dotnet ./main.proto ./sub.proto`.